# rails form for model select box with 1-dimensional data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, drop-down-menu, html-select

I want to limit the entry possibilities for a text field in my model to a previously defined array.

How do I make an `options_for_select` with just a 1-dimensional array like `["foo","bar","foobar"]`?

I tried

```
form_for @mappings do |f|
  f.select(:mapping_type, options_for_select(["foo","bar","foobar"]), class: "..."

end
```

But the select box comes out all messed up like this:

```
<select name="section_mapping[mapping_type]" id="section_mapping_mapping_type">
```

as opposed to what it should be:

```
<select name="mapping_type" >
```

EDIT:

I changed the `f.select` to `select_tag` and the form shows up without any errors but when I submit it, it leaves that field empty

EDIT 2:

`f.collection_select(:mapping_type, options_for_select([...]), class: "..."`

works as in it submits the form with the value correctly, but the HTML class is not applied. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you want to be able to tie your collection select to a property of the object (in your case, `@mappings`)

Also, from the doc on [rails collection_select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select), it will take options as follow:

> collection_select(object, method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {}) public

- **Objet:** the object you are binding the selected option to (@mappings [`f`]) in this case
- **method:** The property/attribute of the object (in this case, `mapping_type`)
- **collection:** The collection for select ( `["foo","bar","foobar"]` )
- **value_method:** The value you want to send back with the submit (Note that this is a `method` which means you should be able to call it on an object.) more on this later.
- **text_method:** The value you want to show as text on the select option on the view (this is also a method as above, more on this later as well)
- **options:** any additional option you want, (e.g: `include_blank`)
- **html_options:** eg: `id`, `class` etc.

As concerning the `value_method` and `text_method`, these are methods that should be called on your `collection`, which means that your collection will be an array of objects.

To this end, you can have the following:

```
class CollectionArr
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :name
  ARR = [
    {"name" => "foo"},
    {"name" => "bar"},
    {"name" => "foobar"}
  ]

  def self.get_collection
    ARR.collect do |hash|
      self.new(
        name: hash['name']
      )
    end
  end
end
```

From here, calling `CollectionArr.get_collection` will return an array of objects where you can cal `.name` to return either `foo`, `bar`, or `foobar`. This makes using the `collection_select` and easy deal from here:

```
<%= f.collection_select : mapping_type, CollectionArr.get_collection, :name, :name, {:include_blank => "Select one"} %>
```

And all is green...

Comment: wow thanks so much. this fixes what I had and I learned a cool thing about collections. Could you include a link to the docs explaining the self.get_collection method contents, specifically what self.new() does.

Comment: Well, I wrote that method... but the key thing here is the `collect` which loops over the array given, and the `self.new` which creates a new instance of the `CollectionArr` class.

Comment: Hope your question was answered?